# Google MapsのAPIで経由地を追加したい

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps PlatformのMaps JavaScript APIで始点と終点の間に経由地を追加したいのですが、無理ですか？可能であれば、書き方を教えてください。

Comment: マルチポスト⇒ https://qiita.com/fsaffgs/questions/92344aebfc38c6970d83

Answer (score 3):

Google Mapsの[ルートサービス](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)で経由地を追加するには、リクエストの`waypoints`プロパティで経由地の配列を指定します。リクエストは次のような形になります。

```
{
  origin: '出発地',
  destination: '目的地',
  waypoints: [
    {
      location: '停車しない経由地1',
      stopover: false
    },{
      location: '停車する経由地2',
      stopover: true
    }],
  // ... その他のオプション
}
```

詳しくは、下記ドキュメントを参照してください。

- [ルートサービス  |  Maps JavaScript API  |  Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)
- [Directions  |  Maps JavaScript API  |  Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions)
- [Waypoints in Directions  |  Maps JavaScript API  |  Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints)